# Debugging Jquery on page load only

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome, firebug

Okay so I'm familiar with a few techniques for debugging events attached to elements. Events like click, mousedown, focus, etc.

Those are easy, but what I am trying to do is log the sequence of events triggered by jquery plugins (like sliders, form plugins, etc) when the document loads. There is some native markup what gets mutated when the page loads and new elements are introduced and some old ones changed or deleted.

Now I tried chrome tools and firefox and setting breakpoints to break on subtree modification on certain elements I'm sure are being changed but that only works after the page is finished loading.

What method would you guys suggest for debugging this kind of situation?

There is no code involved, its just an abstract, general situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the page has finished loading, click on the "pause" button in Chrome Developer Tools, refresh the page, and it will pause right away -- you would be able to step through until the point you want prior to load. Make sure  JQuery file, plugins, etc. are on the Development, unminified versions for this to work.